# Android Firebase Analytics isn't working (stuck on "Run your app to verify installation")

Tags: android, firebase

Have a problem with connecting Firebase to the specific project. In Android Studio this project was successfully connected to Firebase Assistance. Cloud Messaging is working, but analytics isn't displaying.
Project settings:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.3.1"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Module settings:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4'
    ...
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

To fix the problem have tried:
1)Different versions of google-services and firebase-analytics
2)Uninstall and install on different devices
3)Moving 'apply plugin' to the top of the file
4)Re-downloading google-services.json

Comment: Please contact Firebase support directly if something is not working the way you expect in the Firebase console.  We on Stack Overflow don't really have visibility into the inner workings of your Firebase project.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Also, consider running `flutter clean` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long journey, I found certain Firebase connectivity nuances.

1)After successfully connecting Firebase if within the next half hour there are no events, an error about connecting the SDK will be shown until an event appears.
2)If you have previously connected Google maps, then you may have a file with the name "google_maps_api.xml", in which there may be a line with the key "google_app_id", which is why Analytics is not working and events do not reach. You need to comment on it.

Additional little issue.
When you connect analytics through the Firebase Assistant, you may need to comment on the plugin of the Fabric, otherwise, an error will occur.

And a few more tips.
If you have old dependencies of Google analytics, then it is better to remove them.
When you connect analytics through Firebase Assistant, do not forget to remove the old json, as well as comment on the dependencies of the Firebase and google plugin.
Also a solution to your problem could be increasing or decreasing the dependencies versions.
Do not delete your Fabric key even after you've migrated. For now, the Fabric key stays.
You can also try to reproduce your problem using this [example](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but after adding firebase analytics

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:17.5.0'
```

And logged a simple analytic on my main activity onCreate, I got the notification of verified install.

```
val analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this)
with(Bundle()) {
     putString("Splash", "test")
     analytics.logEvent("Splash", this)
}
```